# Selectin rows with double limit options

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a system which will show the 300 highest ranked players for a MMO game which can, and usually do, change daily. So here is what I am trying to do:

Select the top 300 players, and for those 300 players, I want to select the 30 last entries from the same table in which I select which is the current top 300.

Here is my current query, which succesfully and accuratly selects the top 300 players.

```
SELECT * FROM `experiencehistory` WHERE `worldid` = `7` ORDER BY `experiencehistory`.`date` DESC, `experiencehistory`.`rank` ASC LIMIT 300
```

This is my Database structure:

```
ID - Identifies the entry for deletions etc later on.
Characterid - Which character does this entry belong to.
worldid - On which world does this character exist
rank - what is the current (at the time of the entry, which is daily) rank the player has
date - what date was the entry made on. (It saves a date through mktime() which is the day at 4am, all date entries for a specific date is the same.
```

Now, using the above query I have the players as been stated before, how can I make this query also fetch their last 30 entries? I, and I didn't think it'd work well which it didn't, to simply loop through and do another query per character. This ended up with 10-15 seconds page loads and using ALOT of resources, which obviously wouldn't work in a live environment.

I'm thinking about using Group by, but I am not sure how I would go about selecting them regardless. Thankful for any and all help.

Comment: So you would want up to 30 records per player, for a maximum of 9000 records? Or would you want to aggregate them somehow in the main character row?

Comment: It makes no sense to me, can you please rephrase this sentence: *I want to select the 30 last entries from the same table in which I select which is the current top 300.*

Comment: What Cyberbit said, thanks for understanding me. I'm not very good at english but you got exactly what I wanted to do. So yes, that would be 9000 records. I am gonna consolidate it into weekly and monthly changes (that part is working and so I only need to figure out how to extract the data).

Answer (score 0):

From your post, I could not guess how you're gonna fetch the 30 entries from each player, but you could do this to run some code for each player:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `experiencehistory` WHERE `worldid` = 7 ORDER BY `experiencehistory`.`date` DESC, `experiencehistory`.`rank` ASC LIMIT 300"

if ($link->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $link->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

            // do what you have to do to get the 30 entries here.

            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($link->next_result());
}
```

`$link` is your connection...

Hope it works!